# Finding the whether the element of the Array is last or not in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

Lets suppose we have an array

```
p = String.new
a = ['d','e','f','g','h']
a.each do |value|
 p << value
 p << "%" if value is not last
end
```

I need to determine whether the a['h'] is the last index value or not?

Is there a shortcut way to find it like a.is_last?()

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using your specific example, you can just use [Array.join](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000239). You can then replace your example with:

```
a = ["d", "e", "f", "g", "h"]
p = a.join("%") # d%e%f%g%h
```

Comment: a * ("%") is a shortcut. +1 anyway

Answer (score 2):

I have done this in the way

```
p = String.new
a = ['d','e','f','g','h']
a.each do |value|
 p << value
 p << "%" if a.last != value
end
```

I need other then this?

Comment: What if you had duplicated elements in an array, one of them being the last one ?